# retrieving variables with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

```
 <div class="lead_detail_box_routing">


<div class="lead_detail_box_left">location 1</div>
<div class="lead_detail_box_right">Route</div>
<div class="lead_detail_box_left">location 2</div>
<div class="lead_detail_box_right">Route</div>
<div class="lead_detail_box_left">location 3</div>
<div class="lead_detail_box_right">Route</div>
<div class="lead_detail_box_left">location 4</div>
<div class="lead_detail_box_right">Route</div>

<div id="results" style="text-align:center;"></div>  

</div>     <!-- end lead_detail and routing-->
```

e.g. when user clicks on "route" I want my jquery-manual-routing.php to get the "3" ..

so far I have:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a#route").click(function() {
            $("#results").load( "jquery-manual-routing.php", { route_to: ???? } );
            return false;
        });
    });    
    </script>
```

so in my php script, when the user clicks on `route` next to `location 3` I want to be able to grab `$_GET['route_to'] =3;`

Also note that my table already has the class assigned since I am using css to style it

The answer will be pure php echo

Comment: Show your HTML.  Also, what are you going to do with the server response, and what content type will the response be (XML, JSON, HTML, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

fill in the url of the anchor tags with the actual link you need then override the default click action with your jquery function

```
<a class="route" href="jquery-manual-routing.php?route_to=1">route to destination 1</a><br/>
<a class="route" href="jquery-manual-routing.php?route_to=2">route to destination 2</a><br/>
<a class="route" href="jquery-manual-routing.php?route_to=3">route to destination 3</a><br/>
<a class="route" href="jquery-manual-routing.php?route_to=4">route to destination 4</a> etc...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.route").live('click', function() { // live is better
        $("#results").load( $(this).attr('href') );
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: im getting: 

Error: missing ) after argument list
Source File: lead_detail.php?lead_id=68443
Line: 139, Column: 49
Source Code:
        $("#results").load( $(this).attr('href') } );

Comment: that worked wonderful thanks everyone! 

It would be nice to have a "wait while loading" div show up when the ajax is called, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#route").click(function(event) {
        link = $(event.target);

        $("#results").load( "jquery-manual-routing.php", { route_to: link.text() } );

        return false;
    });
});
```

That would call `jquery-manual-routing.php?route_to=location 3`

Answer (score 0):

If going by the HTML you provided this is a possible solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.lead_detail_box_right").click(function() {
            $("#results").load( "jquery-manual-routing.php", { route_to: $(this).prev().text().replace("location ", "") } );
        });
    });    
</script>
```

Grab the [previous](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) element and get the number in the text.  I used [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp), you can also use [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the number from the text: (*this* is the clicked div)

```
$(this).text().replace(/.*?(\d+)$/, '$1')
```

Getting it from the position of the div:

```
$('.lead_detail_box_left').index(this) + 1
```